# Read 4 tables and write into 1 Hbase Table. How?

Tags: hbase

How to Read 4 tables and write into 1 Hbase Table in one program?  is it possible? Give me some sample coding.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **Yes**.

The slightly longer version is: *Depends*.

We know next to nothing about your situation. This makes it very hard to give a more meaningful answer.

I have a Hadoop job that runs a Hive query that uses 4 tables and the results are put into hive.
I've implemented this exact process 3 different ways.

It's possible... but there isn't enough information about your case to be of any more help.

When asking for help, it's best to include what you've done or what you are considering so people know what to address. I've used Hive as the source for my 4 tables, maybe you are using MySQL... my answer relating to hive coulb be next to useless.

EDIT: Following the 'update' to your conditions:
What have you tried?
Where are you having trouble?

As a starting point, I'd look at the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase` and `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client` package to see what they contain and search for examples using classes such as `HTable` and `HBaseConfiguration`.

It works better when you provide the steps you've taken, what you've tried and the trouble you've run into. That allows members of SO to help you with your situation; instead of asking that it be solved (apparently start to finish) for you.